Is there an android app that provides you with an plan to view nearby touristic spots in a given city?
Say you're at a specific location in a given city, and denote by A,B, C...etc. the touristic spots in the city that you're not aware of, since you're new to this city). Now say you want a plan like this:
From your location, go to place A by walk/transport, from A go to B by walk/transport, then from B, go to C etc.
Is there an android app that does just that, so that you don't need to figure what you've to visit first, and then what to see next etc. The app will plan it for me in the way I described above.
Thank you!

The app will plan what you want to see? How exactly?

A simple search for top 10 sights in (insert name of location) has always done for me, no app required.

But he looks for an app which also to tell you how to get from a sight to the next one and by which means and whats the best order for visiting if you want to do multiple sights in a row.

There is, and has been, a multitude of apps that, more or less, do what you want.
The most obvious one is Google Maps; it can tell you what's of interest around you, and, in many places, it can tell you how to get there. But, realise, that, using Google Maps, you will end up seeing and doing exactly that what everyone else is seeing, and doing, too.
More recently, AI tourist planners have been trying to muscle into this market. Examples include Wanderbot, Tripplanner, PathPal, and many others. (Not affiliated to any of those.)
My advice, however, would be to, at most, be informed by solutions like the above, and to find your own way, and be drawn by what interests you, instead. To get you in a mindset for this, I recommend Derive App. (This is an app I'm responsible for.)
